# Who provide the data for wifi display?

Tags: android, android-ndk, wifi-direct, vnc-server, surfaceflinger

I try to follow the wifi display codes in Android Jelly bean 4.2. In wifi display, the `PlaybackSession` class will be responsible for getting the data. And finally it will get the data from a class called `SurfaceMediaSource`, which inherits from `MediaSource`. The data is in `BufferQueue` in `SurfaceMediaSource`. But I cannot find who is responsible for write the data to the `BufferQueue`. I believe the `SurfaceFlinger` should do it. However, I cannot find any specific codes. Does anyone know how it works?

Comment: It's using the "virtual display" feature in surfaceflinger.

Answer (score 0):

Check `onDisplayConnected()` call in `wfd.cpp` and `com.android.server.display.DisplayDevice`.
Both will end up in `SurfaceComposerClient::setDisplaySurface()` in `frameworks/native/libs/gui/SurfaceComposerClient.cpp`.

Sadly I don't understand how setting of `DisplayState::eSurfaceChanged` would cause the display to be rendered to the `BufferQueue` in `SurfaceMediaSource`.